# Core Data concurrency with new iOS 5 thread options

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data

I'm using the new iOS 5 core data concurrency options. I have two threads:

```
mainContext: NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
backgroundContext: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, parent = mainContext
```

I have an object called squareObject which is currently fetched and owned by the main context. I modify a property of this object, say

```
squareObject = [getSquareObjectForContext:mainContext];
squareObject.isPendingChange = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

Then I save this context. Now, I execute a fetch on the backgroundContext:

```
[backgroundContext performBlock^{
    ...
    pendingSquares = [[appDelegate.serverMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
    [pendingSquares filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isPendingChange == YES"]];
}];
```

However, I do get items back, but none of them have the new value of 1 for isPendingChange.

Why have the changes not propagated to the backgroundContext? According to the documentation:

> Changes you make to a managed object in one context are not propagated
>   to a corresponding managed object in a different context unless you
>   either refetch or re-fault the object.

So I did refetch, but the changes were not committed. And I don't think I really need to save the mainContext after making changes for them to appear in the backgroundContext, right?

If the square object is owned by the backgroundContext, then everything works fine:

```
   squareObject = [getSquareObjectForContext:backgroundContext];
   squareObject.isPendingChange = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

Obviously, these changes appear when I fetch in the backgroundContext since the changes were made on that context. I'm just not understanding why the child context is unable to fetch changes made by the parent context using a brand new fetch request. I thought this was the way to do it?

Comment: I think you should save context for reflecting it to persistent storage. After that you should refetch in the background thread to retrieve new values.

Comment: Even with saving, it doesn't appear in the child context when I fetch..

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdChangeManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001201-SW5).

Comment: I still have to register for change notifications with the new iOS 5 threading options?

Comment: It says so in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I did refetch, but the changes were not committed. And I don't think I really need to save the mainContext after making changes for them to appear in the backgroundContext, right?

This assumption is incorrect. You do have to save the child context for the changes to appear in the parent context.

But when you save the parent context, it automatically triggers saving child context first.

> Even with saving, it doesn't appear in the child context when I fetch.

This is because changes are propagated from child to parent, not the other way around.

Comment: So then if I save on the parent, and do a fetch on the child, shouldn't this child fetch have the latest values for the object, without having to call refresh object? I don't see why it wouldn't work like that..

Comment: Because the relationship between works only in one direction. Saved changes are moved from child to parent. It is not designed to work the other way around. That is why you don't see the changes in child context without refreshing.

Comment: But isn't a fetch a refresh of its own? It says in the documentation "Changes you make to a managed object in one context are not propagated to a corresponding managed object in a different context unless you either refetch or re-fault the object."

Comment: Re-faulting probably works, since that forces a roundtrip to the parent context or a persistent store. Refetching itself is actually not enough since cache mechanism gets on your way.

Comment: And what's also weird is that if I make changes to the object on the parent context, SAVE on the CHILD context, fetch on the child, then now the object has the pending changes. What's up with that?

Comment: Saving child context transports all changes from child context to parent context. I'm guessing the changes are being merged in the process.

Comment: So if I'm dealing with say 100 objects that have been fetched on the child context that might have changes on the parent context, is it more efficient to call save ONCE on the CHILD context before the fetch, or call refreshObject 100 times, once for each object?

Comment: Or you could just call reset on child context and then refetch all. Just know that all your managed object references that are tied to that child context are being invalidated with the _reset_. But if you are going to refetch them anyway, you won't care.

Comment: Hahahaha I just realized you're the same person on the devforums! I thought I would ask on both to make sure I get consistent answers ;)

Comment: But then this would cause any pending changes on the child to be wiped out right?

Comment: :) That's true. The merge is definitely slower, but the benefit would be to have a true merge instead of resolving it with whatever the parent has.